# xampp linux run executables with php

Tags: php, linux, xampp

My goal is essentially to run executable(say .sh or .py) with with php code, where executable would potentially create some new files in the directory.

For example, an obvious first try (shell_exec):

```
<?php
    $output = shell_exec('sh shell.sh');
    echo $output;
?>
```

Where the shell file is:

```
#!/bin/bash
# My first script

whoami
mkdir "NewDir"
```

Does not fully work if executed by visiting a page. `whoami` command returns "daemon" (not my account name) and folder "NewDir" is not being created.

I think this is permissions problem, even though my htdocs folder has permissions 777. (What I am trying to do works on Windows).

I think if I could make this simple script create a directory then my original would be resolved.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Well actually this is quite simple. Get the .py or the .sh file and use:

```
<?php
Include_once 'filename';
?>
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: Including .sh file simply prints its contents rather than executes it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the full path in your bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
# My first script

whoami
mkdir /tmp/testFolder
```

Make it executable and set permissions to Folder:

```
chmod +x bashscript.sh
chmod 777 /tmp/testFolder
```

Test to start it:

```
./bashscript
```

Then everything should woring

Comment: Dear Patrick, it indeed allows me to create a directory in /tmp/ with an owner "daemon". That's a progress, thank you!